# 302 redirect response when exposing localhost Magento via ngrok

Tags: apache, magento, magento2, virtualhost, ngrok

I have setup a local Magento 2 which can be accessed via browser or curl command as expected:

1. http://localhost/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
2. http://localhost

I have a task to expose the local environment, so that some service can be tested by other people, so I chose ngrok. I started ngrok by using these commands:

1. ngrok http --host-header=localhost 80
2. ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 80

But all of them got the same result: 302 redirect infinitely.

Here is Apache log when I run curl http://localhost/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html, and the log is the same exact that the last line is "302" instead of "200" when I curl the corresponding ngrok url

```
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] add path info postfix: /var/www/magento2/pub/men -> /var/www/magento2/pub/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/magento2/pub/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html -> men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'men/tops-men/jackets-men.html'
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] add path info postfix: /var/www/magento2/pub/men -> /var/www/magento2/pub/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/magento2/pub/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html -> men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'men/tops-men/jackets-men.html'
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] add path info postfix: /var/www/magento2/pub/men -> /var/www/magento2/pub/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/magento2/pub/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html -> men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'men/tops-men/jackets-men.html'
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] rewrite 'men/tops-men/jackets-men.html' -> 'index.php'
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php -> /index.php
[rid#ffffbdc980a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#ffffbdc8d760/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php -> index.php
[rid#ffffbdc8d760/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'
[rid#ffffbdc8d760/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php -> index.php
[rid#ffffbdc8d760/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'
[rid#ffffbdc8d760/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php -> index.php
[rid#ffffbdc8d760/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'
[rid#ffffbdc8d760/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/magento2/pub/] pass through /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php
192.168.65.1 - - [26/Sep/2023:08:28:04 +1000] "GET /men/tops-men/jackets-men.html HTTP/1.1" 200 4407 "-" "curl/8.1.2"
```

Here is result in browser

[image]

Here is the screenshot information provided by ngrok

[image]

Thanks for any information that can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is found by updating the store configuration in Magento: Stores / Config / General / Web / Url Options / Auto-redirect to Base URL to No fixed the issue for me.

the solution was found here: https://github.com/shkoliar/magento-ngrok/issues/3#issuecomment-652586969